# pipeline Source for DSL

Tags: jenkins, dsl, cloudbees, jenkins-workflow, spring-dsl

I'm starting to work on pipelines for jenkins (formerly workflow)

I'm using IntelliJ for an IDE

Is there a source of Documentation for GDSL or some way I can know what groovy is acceptable in the pipeline and what is not?

Also is there a way that I can test run the GDSL before having to check in my Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a source of Documentation for GDSL

Yes, as of [1.13](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/CHANGES.md#113-jan-18-2016) you can download a GDSL schema from *Snippet Generator* and install it in IDEA. There are some aspects missing—for example step return types are not defined in this schema. Last I checked it also did not offer completion on, for example, known `$class` implementations for `step`; this information *is* available in the *Snippet Generator* UI and downloadable HTML reference documentation.

> is there a way that I can test run the [script?] before having to check in my Jenkinsfile?

There is not currently an offline test feature; it would be tricky since everything in a Pipeline script is intended to be interacting with a live Jenkins service. (If you have other logic in there, it would be better factored out into external scripts in the language of your choice.)

As of [1.14](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/CHANGES.md#114-feb-25-2016) there is a **Replay** link you can use to iteratively test proposed changes before committing to `Jenkinsfile`, and you can [use this from the CLI too](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/replay-pipeline).

Comment: "Yes, as of 1.13 you can download a GDSL" <- every time I click mine I get a stack dump.. So I guess if it does work I should submit a bug..   though I don't know why it needs to be tied to one's Jenkins.  Would be great if it was just available with instructions for how to install it.. 

"Replay"  I LOVE that feature and use it regularly..  but it does not autocomplete.. :-)